# Error when returning multiple values to threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mingw, mingw32

I set up several threads, each of them would be filled with multiple values and it should make query to DB and return multiple values.

The single thread can display the correct values, but something went wrong when they return values to main function.

The main function is:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    struct thread_args* args = malloc(sizeof(*args));
    args->str = str;
    args->tri_input = tri_input;
    args->length = length;
    res = pthread_create(&t_id[i], NULL, threads, args);
    if(res != 0)
        printf("Failed to create %d th thread.\n", i);
}

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    void *returnRes;
    pthread_join(t_id[i], &returnRes);
    indicesArr[i] = returnRes;
    printf("in main thread, indicesArr[%d].length: %d\n", i, indicesArr[i] -> length);
}
```

The single thread:

```
void *threads(void *args_){

    struct thread_args *args = (struct thread_args *)args_;
    char* str = args -> str;
    struct IntArrLenArr* indicesArr = NULL;
    indicesArr = malloc(sizeof(*indicesArr));
    int length = args -> length;
    PGconn *dbconn = DBconnect(str);
    *indicesArr = duncitonReturnIndicesArr(dbconn);
    printf("in threads, indicesArr -> length: %d\n", indicesArr->length);
    free(args);
    PQfinish(dbconn);
    return indicesArr;
}
```

The result was as following:

```
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 0
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 0
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 4
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 0
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 0
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 4
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 4
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 0
in main threads, indicesArr[0].length: -1949512500
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 2
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 4
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 4
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 1
in threads, indicesArr -> length: 4

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 6.551 s
Press any key to continue.
```

It seems works well if it is compiled by mingw64 on win10, but somehow I have to compile it in 32 bit. My IDE is Codeblocks, differs from mingw64, I had to add a linker `MinGW\lib\libpthread_s.dll.a` and `MinGW\lib\libpthread.a` there when I compile it with mingw32. I don't know if it could be the problem? and how could I fix it?

Comment: Questions like this require a [mcve]. Consider using valgrind to detect some failure and make sure you compile with warnings enabled, this should avoid a few common bugs. Please also [edit] your question and replace the image with text. Images can't be searched and pose challenges for people that are visually impaired.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the hints, I did that

Comment: Let's say: minimal _complete_ reproducible example Something that compiles without warnings, I'd like to add. Preferably without database-usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I return the values was actually not a problem. That was problem at the libraries I used. 
So I use Mingw installation manager (which should be installed by default) to reinstall the `min3gw2-libpthread...` libraries. and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more careful about the use of  [`pthread_join()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html):

- first, before using the return value, you need to check if the function succeeded. Otherwise your return value will not be what you expect.
- you also should initialize your pointer for the retvalue.

Comment: The values in a single thread was correct, I mean, before returning values to main function. As for the second point, you mean the variable `returnRes' ? should I initialize it in any other way?

Comment: @heisthere Yes! You must set the retval pointer to point to a valid address of a pointer BEFORE calling join: see linked doc, second para of the section “DESCRIPTION”

Comment: Could you please me tell me where exact should I revise my code? I changed `pthread_join(t_id[i], &returnRes);' to `pthread_join(t_id[i], (void **)&returnRes);`, that did not work. And I noticed that the instruction was under unix where I work on window, don't know if that makes any difference, or I just did it wrong.

Comment: Actually, `void *returnRes` should be set to `NULL` before calling `pthread_join(... &returnRes)` to avoid potential hazards in problematic cases.